# Cannot Create SD with Eclipse AVD on Mac 10.5

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, sd-card, android-virtual-device

EDIT: I'm sorry if I haven't provided enough information.  But if you would need some bit of information to be able to answer this, please just let me know what it is and I'll put it up here.

I am trying to create an AVD with Eclipse 3.8 (Juno) on my Mac OS X 10.5.8.  When I open the AVD Manager and click 'new' I have to chose:

AVD Name

Device

Target

CPU/ABI

SD Card Size/File

before I can hit 'OK.'  When I've made a selection for each of these and hit 'OK,' I remain in the 'create new AVD' window but receive the error in Eclipse:

```
[2013-03-13 18:29:51 - SDK Manager] dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
[2013-03-13 18:29:51 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.
[2013-03-13 18:29:51 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.
```

I know there are similar questions to mine, but most of the solutions offered are given in terminology that is beyond me.  If you have an idea of how to help me, please speak to me simply.  Thank you.